# How to set background color for custom color

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I show data with custom text color and how can I set background color with Javascript / alpinejs 2.2 to be text always good visible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Depending on your text color, "good visible" background color can be almost everything. What is your text color?

Comment: Perhaps use some of these ideas: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+color+contrast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Alpine.js you can bind the `style` attribute:

```html
<div x-data="{ background: '#333' }" x-bind:style="`background-color: ${background}`">Dark grey background container</div>
```